# Add a special value to a variable

Tags: linux, variables

I want to add a special value to the value of a variable. this is my script:

```
x    55;
y    106;
```

now I want to change the value of `x` from `55` to `60`.

Generally, how can we apply a math expression on the values of variables in a script?

Comment: Which shell or language do you use?  I do not know of one that assigns variable values with an `=` sign or something.  Add a tag with that please.

Comment: Im using ubunto

Comment: this is not a real variable! Im a new in ubuntu, so I have a file in which there is an "x". beyond x is it's value. I want to add a number to that. how can I do that?

Comment: Ha ok, Ubuntu.  This is a linux distribution.  Then the file can be in many languages (bash or other shell, C, Perl, Java, Python, ...).  Could you tell us the name of the file and print it's content in your question please?  The answer will vary based on the language used!

Comment: I have written it in c++ lang.

Comment: ok, C++ syntax is not like what you posted above.  `x = x + 5;` or `x = 60;`.  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/.    You have a long but fun road ahead :-)

Comment: I was wrong, this script is not based on C++ (my based code was). I have a script in ubuntu that I want to add a number to the other number in a text file (like what I have written above). how can I write this script.

Answer (score 0):

Others might come up with something simpler (ex: sed, awk, ...), but this quick and dirty script works.  It assumes your input file is exactly like you posted:

```
this is my script.
x    55;
y    106;
```

And the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: usage $0 <file>"
    exit 1
else
    inputfile=$1
    if [ ! -f $inputfile ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: could not find $inputfile"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

tempfile="/tmp/tempfile.$$"
>$tempfile

while read line
do
    firstelement=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    if [ "$firstelement" == 'x' ]
    then
        secondelement=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d';' -f1)
        (( secondelement = secondelement + 5 ))
        echo "$firstelement    $secondelement;" >>$tempfile
    else
        echo "$line" >>$tempfile
    fi
done <$inputfile

mv $tempfile $inputfile
```

So it reads the input file line per line.  If the line starts with variable x, it takes the number that follows, does +5 to it and outputs it to a temp file.  If the line does not start with x, it outputs the line, unchanged, to the temp file.  Lastly the temp file overwrite the input file.

Copy this code in a file, make it executable and run it with the input file as an argument.